# IntelliJ FileWatcher for SCSS not working

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, file-watcher

I would like to work in IntelliJ with SCSS files.
I see [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html) and I try to follow it. But for some reason this is not working for me.

WHAT I DID:

(I have a mac computer)
I download the node sass library : `npm install -g sass`
I add file watcher :

```
Scope : All Places
Program : usr/local/bin/node-sass
Arguments : --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Output paths to refresh: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

But if I create `.scss` file and save it, it doesn't create any `.css` file.

Comment: What file type is chosen in the file watcher settings? Also, have you tried indicating `sass` instead of `node-sass`?

Comment: Yes I did. I figure out what the stupid mistake it was. Instead of usr/local/,.. I should put /usr/local/,... :D

Answer (score 4):

Arguments you have specified are valid neither for `Sass` nor for `node-sass`.
For Sass (`npm install -g sass`) the most simple setup is:

[image]

For node-sass (`npm install -g node-sass`), it would be:

[image]